# Docker flask uwsgi 404 on a remote host

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, docker, flask, uwsgi

**Update 2**

I configure my routes in configure_blueprints called from create_app. I don`t want put all my views handlers in uwsgi.py. They are stored in separate modules.

```
def configure_blueprints(app):
    from .root import root_bp
    ...
    blueprints = [
        (root_bp, None),
        ...
    ]
    for bp, endpoint in blueprints:
        app.register_blueprint(bp, url_prefix=endpoint)
    return app


def create_app(config_fn=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../templates', static_folder='../static')
    ...
    configure_blueprints(app)
    return app
```

app/root/views.py

```
root_bp = Blueprint('root_bp', __name__)

@root_bp.route('/')
def root():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/login/')
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Here is output of `SIMPLE_SETTINGS=app.config,instance.docker python3 manage.py list_routes`

```
2017-03-01 06:48:11,381 - passlib.registry - DEBUG - registered 'sha512_crypt' handler: <class 'passlib.handlers.sha2_crypt.sha512_crypt'>
...
root_bp.root                                       HEAD,OPTIONS,GET     /
...
```

This is implementation of the `list_routes` command

```
@manager.command
def list_routes():
    import urllib
    output = []
    for rule in flask.current_app.url_map.iter_rules():
        options = {}
        for arg in rule.arguments:
            options[arg] = '[{0}]'.format(arg)
        methods = ','.join(rule.methods)
        try:
            url = flask.url_for(rule.endpoint, **options)
        except BaseException as e:
            print('Exc={}'.format(e))
        line = urllib.parse.unquote('{:50s} {:20s} {}'.format(rule.endpoint, methods, url))
        output.append(line)
    for line in sorted(output):
        print(line)
```

I do not understand why routes should be placed to a file and can not be configured dynamically. If this does not work, what should I do?

**Update**

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
env = SIMPLE_SETTINGS=app.config,instance.docker
callable = app
wsgi-file = /var/www/app/uwsgi.py
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
socket = /var/www/app/uwsgi.sock
chmod-socket = 666
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/app/app.log
chdir = /var/www/app
plugin = python3
master = true
processes = 1
```

/var/www/app/uwsgi.py

```
from app import create_app
app = create_app()
```

I configure blueprints inside create_app function. I think they should be available at the time of application start. Also I use Flask-script.

```
SIMPLE_SETTINGS=app.config,instance.docker python3 manage.py shell
```

The shell starts without errors.

**Original post**

I have studied all related questions. I could not solve my problem. I deploy my project through the docker-machine on the remote host. Here is my configuration:

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3 python3-pip git libpq-dev libevent-dev uwsgi-plugin-python3 \
    nginx supervisor 

COPY nginx/flask.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/
COPY supervisor/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY . /var/www/app

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/nginx/app /var/log/uwsgi/app /var/log/supervisor \
    && rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default \
    && ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/flask.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask.conf \
    && echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    &&  pip3 install -r /var/www/app/python_modules \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/app \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log

WORKDIR /var/www/app

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - moderator-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  redis:
    image: redis
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.6
  api:
    build: .
    mem_limit: 1000m
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
      - rabbitmq
volumes:
  moderator-redis:
    driver: local
  moderator-db:
    driver: local
```

supervisord.conf

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx

[program:uwsgi]
command=uwsgi --ini /var/www/app/uwsgi.ini
```

flask nginx conf

```
server {

    server_name localhost;
    listen 80 default_server;

    charset utf-8;
    sendfile on;
    client_max_body_size 70M;
    keepalive_timeout  0;

    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffer_size 8k;
    proxy_buffers 2048 8k;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort on;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///var/www/app/uwsgi.sock;
    }

    location /static {
        root /var/www/app/static/;
    }
}
```

$docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                NAMES
d9dec354d97e        moderator_api       "/usr/bin/supervisord"   13 seconds ago      Up 9 seconds        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                   moderator_api_1
243c48dac303        postgres            "docker-entrypoint..."   3 hours ago         Up 14 seconds       5432/tcp                             moderator_db_1
23901a761ef1        redis               "docker-entrypoint..."   3 hours ago         Up 14 seconds       6379/tcp                             moderator_redis_1
7cc0683bfe18        rabbitmq:3.6        "docker-entrypoint..."   3 hours ago         Up 16 seconds       4369/tcp, 5671-5672/tcp, 25672/tcp   moderator_rabbitmq_1
```

tail -f /var/log/uwsgi/app/app.log

```
[pid: 24|app: 0|req: 1/1] 123.23.7.216 () {44 vars in 945 bytes} [Tue Feb 28 14:53:57 2017] GET / => generated 233 bytes in 10 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 3 headers in 311 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

If you need any additional information, please let me know. I tried different configurations: nginx-proxy image, gunicorn etc. I have same problem with the remote host. What am I still missing?

Comment: im no docker expert but if its confirmed `200` from within the docker machine check `iptables` make sure you are accepting flow

Comment: Please share the contents of the file uwsgi.ini file too

Comment: @Busturdust I can see my requests in application log file, it looks like that requests come to application

Comment: @NehalJWani done, I added more details in update

Comment: @ioganegambaputifonguser You have not defined any route for / in your uwsgi application.

Comment: @NehalJWani I have added more information about routes configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a lot of time and was not able to solve the problem with the uwsgi socket. I decided to switch to the [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) HTTP uwsgi web server. I liked the simplicity of setup.

supervisord.conf

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
environment=SIMPLE_SETTINGS="app.config,instance.docker,instance.prod"

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx

[program:app]
command=gunicorn app:app -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --name app --log-level=debug --log-file=- --worker-class gevent
```

nginx flask.conf

```
server {

    server_name your-domain;
    listen 80;

    charset utf-8;
    sendfile on;
    client_max_body_size 70M;
    keepalive_timeout  0;

    root /var/www/app/static/;

    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffer_size 8k;
    proxy_buffers 2048 8k;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort on;

    location / {
      try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }

}
```

One last caveat. I used a flask [snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/35/) with minor modifications for the docker.

```
class ReverseProxied(ProxyFix):
    def __init__(self, app, config, **kwargs):
        self.config = config
        super().__init__(app, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        script_name = environ.get('HTTP_X_SCRIPT_NAME', '')
        if script_name:
            environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = script_name
            path_info = environ['PATH_INFO']
            if path_info.startswith(script_name):
                environ['PATH_INFO'] = path_info[len(script_name):]

        scheme = environ.get('HTTP_X_SCHEME', '')
        if scheme:
            environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = scheme
        # fix for docker to proxy server_name
        server_name = self.config.get('SERVER_NAME')
        if server_name:
            environ['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] = server_name
        return super().__call__(environ, start_response)

...

app.wsgi_app = ReverseProxied(app.wsgi_app, app.config)
```

app/config.py

```
SERVER_NAME = 'localhost:8000'
```

instance/prod.py

```
SERVER_NAME = 'your-domain'
```

Now everything works fine.